# Flyway for Android takes ~500ms to do absolutely no migrations

Tags: android, sqlite, flyway

I have implemented Flyway for my Android app. It went relatively smoothly, however I have noticed a major increase in app startup time. I small increase was expected, but not 500ms - 1s.

I am using flyway 4.0.3

anything suspicious here?

```
 SQLiteDatabase db = context.openOrCreateDatabase(DatabaseManager.DATABASE_NAME, 0, null);
    ContextHolder.setContext(context);

    flyway.setDataSource("jdbc:sqlite:" + db.getPath(), "", "");
    flyway.setBaselineOnMigrate(true);
    flyway.setCallbacks(new MigrationFlywayCallback());
    try {
        flyway.migrate();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        sendMigrationFailedEvent(e);
    }
```

relative log output:

https://gist.github.com/jonschmidt/1fc61b45b1c0bf95baaa5d44f3c204c0

---

EDIT

The problem seems to be in the way FlyWay checks to see whether it should be migrated or not. It checks whether the metadata table has the column version_rank

https://github.com/flyway/flyway/blob/master/flyway-core/src/main/java/org/flywaydb/core/internal/metadatatable/MetaDataTableImpl.java#L68

Internally, this uses SQLDroid to check for the existence of the column, by passing the column name into the columnNamePattern here

https://github.com/SQLDroid/SQLDroid/blob/master/src/main/java/org/sqldroid/SQLDroidDatabaseMetaData.java

Which is never used in that function, so it will always return true, and FlyWay will think it needs to migrate every time you start the app, adding a few hundred ms to the operation.

Answer (score 1):

As the logs say

> Upgrading metadata table "main"."schema_version" to the Flyway 4.0 format ...

Flyway performed a one-off migration from the Flyway 3.x to the Flyway 4.x metadata table format.

Comment: I saw that. It seems to do this every single time I start the application, even though it is successful each time. Seems to be a bug, or perhaps something wrong with my configuration?

Comment: sorry to be persistent, but I see you are a core contributor and might have more insight on this. Is there any reason you can think of that it would run this migration every single time? I have to drop our usage of the library if I cannot solve this which would be a shame, as it buys us quite a lot.

Comment: "I have to drop our usage of the library if I cannot solve this" -> or you could open a debugger and find out what is going on ;-)

Comment: Of course I can. I just thought you might know from the logs alone. I'll tell you what I find out.

Comment: Please check my above response. Maybe you have a suggestion on a fix or workaround? I can look more into it later as well, just pretty busy ATM.